# How to : Skip the Header record from one .csv and Copy the Records to another csv file using command prompt or batch

Tags: csv, batch-file, header, command-prompt, skip

I got a task that says skip the header part of a csv file and copy the rest to another file. I am unable to figure out any way that can do this. I require to do this using command prompt or by writing a batch file code. I tried using for loop but dint worked

Comment: Please share your efforts! This is a site for programmers asking specific questions, but not a free code/script request service; so as long as you do not show your code and describe exactly what you have trouble with, this question is too broad and therefore off-topic here. Please read the [tour] and these help articles: [ask], [mcve]. Thank you!

Comment: Try `for /F "skip=1 delims=" %A IN (file.csv) do (@echo %A)>>file1.csv`. Replace `file.csv` and `file1.csv` with your names

Comment: If the `.csv` file is not tab delimited, _(or contains necessary tabs)_, then the simplest method would be to use the `More` command, `More +1 "SourceDirectory\Input.csv">"DestinationDirectory\Output.csv"`. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `More /?` to read its usage information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the way Compo suggested (using `more` with `+1` which will exclude the first line), you can use a `for /F` loop:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%A IN (file.csv) do (echo %%A)>>file1.csv
```

which, with the option `skip=1` will skip the first line.

Another way would be to loop through the output of `more` command:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%A IN ('more "file.csv"') do (echo %%A)>>file1.csv
```

See the help pages of the following commands in cmd to learn  more:

- `for /?`
- `echo /?`
- `more /?`